# increment and decrement operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Here is the problem I has been trying to solve:

> Define a class named PrimeNumber that stores a prime number. The default constructor should set the prime number to 1. Add another constructor that allows the caller to set the prime number. Also, add a function to get the prime number. Finally, overload the prefix and postfix `++` and `-- operators` so they return a `PrimeNumber` object that is the next largest prime number (for `++`) and the next smallest prime number (for `--`). For example, if the object's prime number is set to 13, then invoking `++` should return a `PrimeNumber` object whose prime number is set to 17. Create an appropriate test program for the class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class PrimeNumber
{
public:
    PrimeNumber() : pNum(1) {}
    PrimeNumber(int setNum) : pNum(setNum) {}
    int getNum() const { return pNum; }
    PrimeNumber operator ++(); //prefix
    PrimeNumber operator ++(int ignoreMe); //postfix
    PrimeNumber operator --();
    PrimeNumber operator --(int ignoreMe);
    bool isPrime(const int& num);
private:
    int pNum;
};

int main( )
{
    int x;
    cout << "enter prime number => ";
    cin >> x;

    PrimeNumber p(x);
    PrimeNumber hold = p++;
    cout << "Value of hold => " << hold.getNum() << endl;
    cout << "Value of p => " << p.getNum() << endl;

    cout << "enter prime number => ";
    cin >> x;

    PrimeNumber p2(x);
    PrimeNumber hold2 = ++p2;
    cout << "Value of hold2 => " << hold2.getNum() << endl;
    cout << "Value of p2 => " << p2.getNum() << endl;

    cout << "enter prime number => ";
    cin >> x;

    PrimeNumber p3(x);
    PrimeNumber hold3 = p3--;
    cout << "Value of hold3 => " << hold3.getNum() << endl;
    cout << "Value of p3 => " << p3.getNum() << endl;

    cout << "enter prime number => ";
    cin >> x;

    PrimeNumber p4(x);
    PrimeNumber hold4 = --p4;
    cout << "Value of hold4 => " << hold4.getNum() << endl;
    cout << "Value of p4 => " << p4.getNum() << endl;


    return 0;
}
bool PrimeNumber::isPrime(const int& num)
{
    if (num < 2)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (num == 2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

PrimeNumber PrimeNumber::operator ++() //prefix
{
    pNum += 1;
    while (!isPrime(pNum))
    {
        pNum++;
    }
    return pNum;
}
PrimeNumber PrimeNumber::operator ++(int ignoreMe) //postfix
{
    int temp = pNum += 1;
    while (!isPrime(pNum))
    {
        temp = pNum;
        pNum++;
    }
    return temp;
}
PrimeNumber PrimeNumber::operator --() //prefix
{
    pNum -= 1;
    while (!isPrime(pNum))
    {
        pNum--;
    }
    return pNum;
}
PrimeNumber PrimeNumber::operator --(int ignoreMe) //postfix
{
    int temp = pNum -= 1;
    while (!isPrime(pNum))
    {
        temp = pNum;
        pNum--;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

The issue is related to decrement operator overloading. I think increment operator works as expected. If don't, please indicate. However, the `hold` values don't seem as expected for postfix increment and decrement operations. How can the issue be fixed. Besides, If there is other correctable mistakes , please indicate.

```
Output                              Expected Output
----------                          -------------------
enter prime number => 11            enter prime number => 11
Value of hold => 12                 Value of hold => 11
Value of p => 13                    Value of p => 13
enter prime number => 11            enter prime number => 11
Value of hold2 => 13                Value of hold2 => 13
Value of p2 => 13                   Value of p2 => 13
enter prime number => 11            enter prime number => 11
Value of hold3 => 8                 Value of hold3 => 11
Value of p3 => 7                    Value of p3 => 7
enter prime number => 11            enter prime number => 11
Value of hold4 => 7                 Value of hold4 => 7
Value of p4 => 7                    Value of p4 => 7
```

Comment: Note that it looks like that both postfix operators do not return the right result.

Comment: Can you give an example what is going wrong? No I did not test, but the logic looks wrong.

Comment: Your postfix operators are all wrong. They should return the **old value** of the object, not the new value plus or minus one.

Comment: I have just realized @n.m. how can it be fixed?

Comment: how can the postfix `hold` issue be fixed? I've edited my question @Wimmel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PrimeNumber PrimeNumber::operator --(int ignoreMe) //postfix
{
    int temp = pNum -= 1;
    while (!isPrime(pNum))
    {
        temp = pNum;
        temp--;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

this code will run forever, cause pNum is not changed inside loop. Your program just hangs after last input, trying to execute postfix `operator--`.

## Edit

Your postfix operator:

```
PrimeNumber PrimeNumber::operator --(int ignoreMe) //postfix
{
    int temp = pNum -= 1;
    while (!isPrime(pNum))
    {
        temp = pNum;
        pNum--;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

is still invalid. This is correct version IMHO:

```
PrimeNumber PrimeNumber::operator --(int ignoreMe) //postfix
{
    int temp = pNum;
    while (!isPrime(--pNum)) {}
    return temp;
}
```

the same for `oprator++(int)`:

```
PrimeNumber PrimeNumber::operator ++(int ignoreMe) //postfix
{
    int temp = pNum;
    while (!isPrime(++pNum)) {}
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So there's some basic issues with your code.

- In general, we want prefix operators to return a reference to themselves.
- Your return values in general are calling an unnecessary implicit PrimeNumber constructor.

Here's a basic rule you can follow:

- **Prefix style:** Perform the increment or decrement as appropriate, and then return `*this`.
- **Postfix style**: Create a copy of yourself by doing `auto copy = *this`, and then call the appropriate prefix operator.

Let's try implementing this:

```
PrimeNumber & PrimeNumber::operator ++() //prefix
{
    pNum += 1;
    while (!isPrime(pNum))
        pNum++;
    return *this;
}

PrimeNumber PrimeNumber::operator ++(int ignoreMe) //postfix
{
    auto copy = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return copy;
}

PrimeNumber & PrimeNumber::operator --() //prefix
{
    pNum -= 1;
    while (!isPrime(pNum))
        pNum--;
    return *this;
}

PrimeNumber PrimeNumber::operator --(int ignoreMe) //postfix
{
    auto copy = *this;
    --(*this);
    return copy;
}
```

Additionally, test code should throw assertions or the like when they give the wrong result. I shouldn't need to think about if a test is right or wrong.

```
int main( ) {
    auto x = PrimeNumber(17);
    auto hold = x++;
    assert(hold.getNum() == 17);
    assert(x.getNum() == 19);

    x = PrimeNumber(18);
    hold = x--;
    assert(hold.getNum() == 18);
    assert(x.getNum() == 17);

    x = PrimeNumber(25);
    hold = ++x;
    assert(hold.getNum() == 29);
    assert(x.getNum() == 29);

    x = PrimeNumber(19);
    hold = --x;
    assert(hold.getNum() == 17);
    assert(x.getNum() == 17);

    cout << "Success!\n"
}
```

This `main()` will only print `Success!` if all of the assertions are true.

Comment: the veteran I'm aware of using reference for prefix but I have read that  `we find it opens the door to too many problems to return by reference with increment or decrement operators, and so we always simply return by value for all versions of the increment and decrement operators.`  in C++ book. I don't use the reference. What do you think about the idea ? Should I use the reference way to prefix increment and decrement operations or not ? Besides, what's the benefit using of `auto` and why did you use it ? Would you mind teaching?

Comment: I'm using `auto` strictly because it's shorter than `PrimeNumber` and it's a bit easier to type.

Comment: About your book (or wherever the quote is from) talking about not returning by reference, I strongly disagree. I don't know what problems they are worried about, but I believe that users would expect `operator++()` to return a reference that they can assign to. I certainly would.

Comment: one point I don't understand that how the postfixes can know prime or not ?

Comment: The postfix operators are calling `PrimeNumber::operator++()` That is, they make a copy of the object, and then call the prefix operator.

Comment: after I had remember involuntarily,integer values were returned . Finally could you tell me how type conversion is being done on the code. Because, `return copy;` is converted to `return PrimeNumber(copy);`

Comment: There is an implicit call to `PrimeNumber(int setNum)`. You can stop that by making PrimeNumber an explicit constructor.